# vi keybindings move to beginning of line with <ctrl> \ what about end of line

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vi

I use the vi key bindings from set -o vi .  I emphasize this because most vi conversations invariably lead to regular vi. and this is not, these are the vi key bindings. anyhow. 
I hit control and '[' to get into command mode from the command line.

Then I hit shift and  '\' (backslash) to go to the beginning of the line. I like it better than using 'Shift ^'. I don't see it documented anywhere and I can't use it in regular vi.

I still use shift $ to go to the end of the line. Does anyone know a different way to go to the end of the line in the vi set -o keybindings besides "shift $". If there is an easter egg command of shift and '\' to get to the beginning of a line, there might be other hidden commands as well - I am looking for one that will get me to the end of the line. One besides 'shift $'

Comment: Why not just use '0' to go to beginning of line? It's easier than either of your alternatives. As far as end of line goes, 'A' will move to end of line, but it also puts you in append mode. Not sure if that is acceptable in your scenario...

Answer (score 0):

The `|` command is used in `vim` to go to a particular column.  You can prefix it with a count (e.g. `13|` to go to column 13), which is 1 if omitted.  Thus the naked `|` command goes to the first column, the same as `0` that casper suggests.  This differs if you have leading whitespace in your command, where `^` will go to the first non-whitespace character, while `0` or `|` will go to the first character, even if it *is* whitespace.

Out of the box, `set -o vi` the only synonym for `$` that I know of is `<end>` (which is unfortunately, waaaaay over there on the keyboard).